# Indenting with respect to another line

Tags: indentation

How can I indent several lines with respect to the position of some text? For example, this is the effect I'm looking for:

```
480-479: Battle of Thermopyle
         Greek Victories at Salamis and Plataea end Persian war
```

Where the the second line is aligned with 'B' of Battle. Is there something similar to the align environment for text?

Comment: If you have "several lines,", I assume you're going to have to allow for breaking at the end of the page, correct?

Comment: Yeah. But for now, a quick-fix that doesn't allow for it is OK (though it would be preferred)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like something which a `tabbing` environment can solve

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabbing}
 480-479: \=Battle of Thermopyle\\
          \>Greek Victories at Salamis and Plataea end Persian war
\end{tabbing}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `tabular`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lp{4in}}
 480-479: & Battle of Thermopyle\\
          & Greek Victories at Salamis and Plataea end Persian war
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The spacing is a little bit different, but then you don't have to battle with extraspace before and after the environment.  Also, this later approach will let you use `longtable` that can span multiple pages.

Comment: Note that with `tabular`, it may be indented with `\parindent`. Prepending it with `\noindent` would remove this indent. Additionally, depending on the width of the second column, you might consider using [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx).